# Extension can't access generic parameters at runtime

Tags: objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, amazon-cognito

I´m using AWS Cognito, in the doc it says I have to add this function.

But I´m getting this error:

Extension of a generic Objective-C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at runtime

```
extension AWSTask {
    public func continueWithExceptionCheckingBlock(completionBlock:@escaping (_ result: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        self.continue({(task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
            if let exception = task.exception {
                print("Fatal exception: \(exception)")
                kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
            }
            let result: AnyObject? = task.result
            let error: NSError? = task.error as NSError?
            completionBlock(result, error)
            return nil
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without context I can't say if you are *actually doing what the error message prompts you with*, but there is an open bug report describing this issue (where no offending code is actually used):

- [SR-2708: Extending ObjC generics in Swift 3 does not compile](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2708)

> **ObjC**:
>
> ```
> @interface MySet<T : id<NSCopying>> : NSObject
> @end
> ```
>
> **Swift**:
>
> ```
> class Foo { }
> struct Bar { }
>
> extension MySet {
>     func foo() -> Foo { return Foo() }
>     func bar() -> Bar { return Bar() }
> }
> ```
>
> Both of the extension methods result in *"Extension of a generic Objective-C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at
> runtime".* However, neither really does anything like that (at least
> not explicitly).

If you read the comments to the bug report, you'll see that a user named 'Vasili Silin' describes having this issue when attempting to extend `AWSTask`, so you might have to consider alternative approaches until this bug is resolved.

Comment: Got this error on an extension I set up for Core Data NSFetchRequest functions. Following one thought in the linked report, I changed my extension to a class. Had to go around changing func calls, but it did work.

Answer (score 26):

For those who have this issue in **Swift 5**, try adding `@objc` modifier to the method. Please find the example below:

```
extension NSLayoutAnchor {

    @objc func constrainEqual(_ anchor: NSLayoutAnchor<AnchorType>, constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        let constraint = self.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: constant)
        constraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to match with what the error message says. Worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I just got the same error and solve it this way :

> extension yourClass where T == yourType {}

Comment: This was my problem. It's more of an issue with Swift not liking an inheritance constraint (T: YourType) when constraining to struct types. In that case, using the explicit equality constraint (T == YourType) fixes a lot of these enigmatic compiler errors.